# Pattern to match list of identical elements

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, pattern-matching

I am looking for a pattern that matches a (possibly empty) list consisting of identical (in the sense of Equal[]) atomic objects, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By pattern, do you mean regular expression?

Comment: Have you tried using a PatternSequence? http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternSequence.html

Comment: @Dan I  Mathematica has _patterns_, i.e., expressions meant for matching Mathematica language/data constructions, and  `StringExpression`s and `RegularExpression`s meant for _strings_. Reddish seems to be referring to patterns.

Comment: I'm referring to Mathematica patterns, not regexps.

Comment: @Ben PatternSequence does not do what I need.

Comment: Did you forget to accept an answer, or is something lacking?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All of the responses so far seem to have missed the requirement that the objects being matched need to be **atomic**. The following does this:

```
Cases[testList, {a___?AtomQ} /; Equal[a]]
```

If you don't define *identical* in the sense of `Equal` you could have used:

```
Cases[testList, {(a_?AtomQ) ...}]
```

With a slightly modified test list you'll see other methods fail the requirement

```
testList = {{1, 1.0, 1.0}, {a, b, c}, {Exp[Pi] + 1, Exp[Pi] + 1, Exp[Pi] + 1}, {}, {3}};
```

they all incorrectly match the 3rd element too.

Comment: Oops.  Yes, I completely missed that.

Comment: Thanks, your three versions with subtly different matching behavior are very instructive.

Comment: @reddish Don't forget to accept the answer you like most. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Does this work for you?

```
testList = {
  {1, 1.0, 1.},
  {a, b, c},
  {0, Exp[Pi*I] + 1.0, Sin[Pi]}
}
Cases[testList, _List?(Equal @@ # &)]
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I usually tend to forget the `_?(cond)` syntax. Nice example to remember it.

Answer (score 6):

Using `Condition`, instead of `PatternTest`:

```
In[31]:= testList = {{1, 1.0, 1.}, {a, b, c}, {0, Exp[Pi*I] + 1.0, 
    Sin[Pi]}, {}, {3}};

Cases[testList, {a___} /; Equal[a]]

Out[32]= {{1, 1., 1.}, {0, 0., 0}, {}, {3}}
```

(and expanding on Mark's list of test cases to cover empty and singleton lists.)